# Hiding flyout of a button

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I got my *DataTemplate* for items and within this *DataTemplate* I have such code:

```
<Button x:Name="DoneButton"
     Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"
     BorderThickness="1"
     Margin="0,0,20,0"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     VerticalAlignment="Center"
     Grid.Column="2"
     Grid.Row="1"
     Width="50"
     Height="50"
     >
     <Image Source="Images/WPIcons/checked.png" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="-10,0,-10,0" />
           <Button.Flyout>
               <Flyout x:Name="myFly">
                    <Grid Margin="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="myNote" Text="Note: " Style="{StaticResource myText}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="40" x:Name="note" Text="{Binding RecentNote, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="CompletedButton"
                                        Command="{Binding CompletedCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        Click="CompletedButton_Click"
                                        Content="Done"
                                        MinWidth="80"
                                        Height="40"
                                        />
                  </Grid>
              </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

After the flyout for the item has been called and user put his data in it I want to hide this flyout as soon as user hits the "Done" button (***x:Name="CompletedButton"***).

I tried to do that in code behind like:

```
private void CompletedButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    Grid grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(button);
    Flyout fly = (Flyout)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(grid);
    fly.Hide();
}
```

But I get cast exception with that I can't cast *ContentPresenter* to *Flyout* so I guess it's not the way I look for.
How I can hide this flyout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with creating global *DependencyObject* on the page. So when you click the button it keeps it and I can call its flyout to *hide()* from button within this flyout. A bit ugly but works like a charm.